# Bash: start remote python application through ssh and get its PID

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-access, pid

I'm creating a little bash script to copy new files from a windows machine to a remote linux centos server (i run this script using the git-shell) then i want to restart the python application thats running in the server to use those new files.

The problem is that everytime i run this script i want to end the actual running process before i start it again, so i want to get the pid of the process i start and save it to a file in the remote host so i can read it from there the next time i run the program and kill it.

My code by now looks similar to this:

```
echo "Copying code files to server..."
# The destination folder has to exist in the server
scp -r ./python/ root@myserver:/root/

echo "Checking for running processes..."

if ssh root@myserver 'ls dmr.pid >/dev/null'; then
    echo "PID file exists, reading file..."
    PID=$(ssh root@myserver 'cat dmr.pid')

    # Terminate the actual process
    echo "Terminating the process with PID '$PID'..."
    ssh root@myserver 'kill $PID'
else
    echo "PID file doesn't exist, not known processes running"
fi

# Restart the server and get the PID
echo "Restarting the server..."
ssh root@myserver 'python /root/python/run_dev_server.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &'

SERV_PID=$(ssh root@myserver 'echo $!')

echo "Saving PID to file dmr.pid"
ssh root@myserver "echo '$SERV_PID' > \"dmr.pid\""

echo "Sucesfully finished!"
```

The important lines are:

```
ssh root@myserver 'python /root/python/run_dev_server.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
SERV_PID=$(ssh root@myserver 'echo $!')
```

the problem with this is that the script finishes but the file ends up empty as well as the $SERV_PID variable.

And if i dont redirect the outputs and just do something like this:

```
SERV_PID=$(ssh root@myserver 'python /root/python/run_dev_server.py & echo $!')
```

i get stuck after "Restarting the server" and never get the PID or the file that will contain it or even the end of the script.

But if i run this right in the console:

```
ssh root@myserver 'python /root/python/run_dev_server.py & echo $!'
```

i get a PID printed to the terminal.

Any advice on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should probably write a shell script on the remote server that does what you want: kill the previous python script using a file containing the pid, run the python script and save the pid in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Kingslndian i solved it by making one single command that did the three steps i required, so with that avoided the problem of running in different shells:

```
 ssh root@myserver 'python /root/python/run_dev_server.py > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > "dmr.pid"'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ssh root@myserver 'python /root/python/run_dev_server.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
SERV_PID=$(ssh root@myserver 'echo $!')
```

With the above code, you are running two ssh commands and the both create two different shells. The problem is `echo $!` gives the most recent background process' ID from the *current* shell which is none.

That is, when you ssh for the second time, it's *new* shell and there's no background process running in it and hence `echo $!` gives no output. This explains why your PID file is empty.

Instead what you can do is to lookup for all instances of your python script and kill them using `killall` command. Or similar idea using `ps` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it gave me the hint i needed, in the end i solved it by making one single command that did the three steps i required so that avoided using different shells.