# Find pid of each process invoked within shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a cron job that kicks off a shell script every 8 hours that in turn invokes a bunch of programs. Sometimes these programs don't terminate gracefully and they get stuck in limbo.

So if my cron'd script (`run_foo_bar.sh`) looks like this:

```
python foo.py
python bar.py
```

... I could have multiple foo's and bar's running concurrently. Right now I get the PID's involved by doing a `ps -ax |grep foo` and then find the runtime using `ps -p $PID -o etime=`  but this gets cumbersome.

The python programs have a bunch of debug statements being printed to the console and the shell script itself is piped to log files. I wanted to find a way that would echo the PID of each process once it's invoked along with its invocation time, so my run_foo_bar.sh would look like this:

```
date
python foo.py
<some magic to find PID>
echo foo.py is running as PID $PID

date
python bar.py
<some magic to find PID>
echo bar.py is running as PID $PID
```

Comment: can't you add something to the python code so it can self-report its PID and put it on std-out? Good luck.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202292/2877364)?

Comment: At present, `python foo.py` will run until `foo.py` exits, at which point there is no PID to get.  Would you please clarify?  Does `foo.py` move itself to the background or something?  How do you know when a process gets "stuck in limbo"?

Comment: @shellter Agreed.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16136863/2877364) says `os.getpid()`.

Comment: @cxw I know that the normal runtime for foo.py is perhaps 2 hours... if I see an instance of it running for (say) a day or more, I consider it stuck in limbo

Comment: But yep, thanks for the suggestions everyone, os.getpid() seems to be the best option at this point. I was trying to keep this at the shell level as the python programs are owned by someone else, but I'll add os.getpid() to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for completeness, on the Python side, you can do:

```
import os, sys
print(os.getpid())
sys.stdout.flush()
```

to dump the current PID.  You may want to print it to a file instead of the terminal so you can pick it up from that file.

In the shell, since you are just waiting for the cron job to run, another option is this (modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202292/2877364)):

```
python foo.py & echo "$!" > "some file somewhere that will hold the PID" ; fg
```

That runs `python foo.py` in the background, saves the pid of the `python` process (which is in `$!` per [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)), and then returns `python` to the foreground so it can run normally.